# Eclipse with Webclipse - JS debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse 4.5 and I've installed Webclipse 2015 CI 8 and Tomcat 8.0. I'm trying to debug an example. But the debugger doesn't stop at a breakpoint. It runs through the whole file and shows

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[methodToCall] is not a function
>       at doExceptions (http://localhost:8080/Webclipse-JSDebug-WebApp-Example/:180:42)
>       at  (http://localhost:8080/Webclipse-JSDebug-WebApp-Example/:181:6)
>       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>       Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[methodToCall] is not a function
>       at doExceptions (http://localhost:8080/Webclipse-JSDebug-WebApp-Example/:180:42)
>       at  (http://localhost:8080/Webclipse-JSDebug-WebApp-Example/:181:6)

What did I do wrong?

I've installed Webclipse 2016 and I've got the same problem. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about the exceptions, however, a possible reason for skipping the breakpoints would be if you right clicked the project and chose debug as -> debug on server.  Instead, select debug as -> JavaScript in JavaEE Web Application. This should start the server and open the application in chrome, pausing at the breakpoints.